# Encoding from WE8MSWIN1252 to UTF8 JAVA

Tags: java, utf-8

I try to convert some text in WE8MSWIN1252 encoding to UTF8 with my JAVA servlets.

I have searched eveywhere on the cyberspace but without any help!

Thank you very much for your help.

Best Regards.

R.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that WE8MSWIN1252 is just Oracle's DB name for Windows-1252. So try that.

Command-line (to try it out):

```
native2ascii -encoding Windows-1252 original.txt temp.txt
native2ascii -encoding UTF-8 -reverse temp.txt translated.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Spring mvc and i have to configure

```
@RequestMapping(value = "xxxx.json", params = {"xxx","xxx"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces={"application/json; charset=Windows-1252"})
```